# Can a regex match pattern for youtube videos be done in a non-greedy way?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I have the following regex pattern which matches youtube videos into my unique pattern of **[URL]youtube url[/URL]**

```
\[(url|u2b)](http|https):\/\/(m.|www.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/ ]{11})(.*?)\[\/(url|u2b)]
```

This works nearly foolproof to extract the youtube video ID, however if I put two youtube videos on the same line then the match will only have 1 result instead of two.  The pattern is trying to match as one piece.

So for example, if i put two youtube videos in on separate lines as follows:

```
[url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9-Sr8RPty4[/url]
[url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9-Sr8RPty4[/url]
```

it works perfectly fine.

**BUT** if I try to combine these two videos into the same line then I have a problem and this will result in only one malformed match:

```
[url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9-Sr8RPty4[/url] [url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9-Sr8RPty4[/url]
```

I am doing all this in Javascript with the .replace function by the way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the inbetween `.+` or `.*` does an anonymous match.

```
\[(url|u2b)](http|https):\/\/(m\.|www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/(?:(?!\/?\1).)*\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?\/|(?:(?!\/?\1).)*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/))([^"&?\/ ]{11})(.*?)\[\/(url|u2b)]
```

I just changed the in-between `.+` or `.*?` to `(?:(?!\/?\1).)*`. It checks for a condition before matching each character. The condition is, it checks for the character going to be matched wont be the starting character of (*`/` (optional) or `u`*) of the string present inside the first capturing group.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mY8tL5/1)